# Edits in a question thread brings up the question again

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, edits, feed

I'd like to suggest not to bump a question if there's only some text editing happening. I see this frequently (using the RSS feed) that questions appear there which are years old, just because someone refined an answer, fixed a typo or something. This is adding quite some noise since I frequently start looking at the question even though there's no additional input necessary.

Didn't expect that this could really be something people want, but ok. So, is it possible to get RSS feeds for tags which include only new questions?

Comment: This is by-design, so that if the OP has updates to their problem, they may get more relevant answers.

Comment: Then look at the `Newest` feed, rather than the `active` feed.  Done.

Comment: I think the response here will be that it's a desired feature, not a problem.

Comment: Every change merits a second look - did somebody do something bad? Or is the question now better for it? (Particularly true for users with full edit which otherwise get no review)

Comment: There's a difference between the OP adding info and someone just fixing a typo in the answer. The latter definitely does *not* need a bump of the question.

Comment: The trouble is that trivial changes can be abusive too - adding an 's' to 'hit' is probably abuse at the beginning of the word, but a sensible fix at the end.

Comment: I don't argue that it is necessary for someone to look over such changes, but for those who want to answer questions these bumps are really disturbing.

Comment: Granted it's annoying and has caused issues with flooding the front page on a number of sites. Some users don't see an issue with it, some do and space out their edits. With peer review active it's a good thing really, as annoying as it can be.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general this is as designed. We want people eyeballing every change:

- Did it fix the question and make it answerable?
- Did it vandalise the question? (Flag please)
- Is the user abusing edits to "bump" with lots of trivial changes? (Flag please)

Even trivial edits (which otherwise go totally unreviewed from uesrs with enough rep) need checking.

You can however get a feed of just the newest questions in a tag, e.g.:

https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/c?sort=newest

Compared to:

https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/c